# Applescript changes : copy the result as list isn't the same

Tags: macos, debugging, applescript, osx-lion, osx-mavericks

I recently discover a bug in some of my applescripts running them on recent computers. The bug come from questions the applescript asks and try to get two answers : the text answer and the button which is returned. Basically, this is the kind of script :

```
display dialog "This is a question" default answer "the text answer" buttons {"button 1", "button2", "button 3"}
copy the result as list to {"the_text", "the_button"}
```

The "copy the result as list is the only way I found to save both the answers, but here is the problem :
In 10.7, applescript returns the result this order : text returned, button returned. And in 10.9, applescript returns the result in the opposite order, first the button, then the text.
Then using the answers is impossible. Do you know a way I could save both of the answers and make it work on 10.7 as on 10.9 ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
set {text returned:the_text, button returned:the_button} to display dialog "This is a question" default answer "the text answer" buttons {"button 1", "button2", "button 3"}
```

EDIT

By coercing the result to a list, you can no longer identify the button returned and text returned properties.

Compare this:

```
display dialog "This is a question" default answer "the text answer" buttons {"button 1", "button2", "button 3"}
```

with this:

```
display dialog "This is a question" default answer "the text answer" buttons {"button 1", "button2", "button 3"}
return the result as list
```

Comment: It seams to work fine, but it doesn't sounds natural to write to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different version of adayzone's answer. It read more like Python's tuple unpacking.

One-liner:

```
set {the_text, the_button} to {text returned, button returned} of (display dialog "This is a question" default answer "the text answer" buttons {"button 1", "button2", "button 3"})
```

Using the `result` intermediary variable:

```
display dialog "This is a question" default answer "the text answer" buttons {"button 1", "button2", "button 3"}
set {the_text, the_button} to {text returned, button returned} of the result
```